# How to handle AccessControlException with ProtectionDomain null

Tags: java-8, security-policy

In a somewhat old and complex Swing application, we have a custom security manager and policy apparently designed to allow everything:

```
/*
 * allow everything ...
 */
grant codeBase "file:${{java.ext.dirs}}/*" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant {
 permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant codeBase "file:${thecompany.codebase}/-"{
 permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

`${thecompany.codebase}` is set as a system property and appears to be read correctly. Up to (including) Zulu Java 8 build **252**, this works as desired: The GUI starts without apparent issues.

However, when I switch to Zulu Java 8 build **262** (or Oracle **261**), I get hundreds of `AccessControlException`s, e.g.:

```
access:
access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getProtectionDomain")
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1336)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:462)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:886)
...
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:171)
```

All of these errors seem to originate in `ForkJoinWorkerThread`s, and the ["access" debug outputs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/troubleshooting-security.html) for the failures all show the same strange "null" `ProtectionDomain`:

```
access:
domain that failed ProtectionDomain null
 null
 <no principals>
 null
```

I do not see any `ProtectionDomain null` in the "access" debug log when using the JDK build 252.

Reading through the [Oracle release notes and bug fixes for update 261](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u261-relnotes.html), I see a lot of security-related issues, but none strike me as being directly related.

So, under what circumstances (if any) is a `ProtectionDomain null` expected, and how does one grant it permissions?

Any idea how to debug this further is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has turned out to be a consequence of a change in behaviour in the JDK 261 update: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8249846

The underlying reason is that `ForkJoinWorkerThread`s created by the `ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory` now (falsely?) get a non-permitting `AccessControlContext INNOCUOUS_ACC` assigned.

Comment: The linked bug report is about *subclasses* of `ForkJoinWorkerThread`. Are you subclassing it? As otherwise, giving them no permissions is precisely the point of JDK-8237117.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I had linked the wrong bug (there are a few related ones there); I have updated the answer. Which parts of that change were intended (and which were regressions) I will leave for the Java people to decide.